# Does only firefox switch events on a blocking synchronous XMLHttpRequest? What is the future?

Tags: javascript, firefox, standards

I expected the following code to output only 0 or 2, but in Firefox 24 it sometimes outputs 1. Is this according any (future) standard? I think Firefox switches event when the timeout event is blocked by the synchronous call. I was not able to reproduce it in Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m (I entered this code in the console while having a website opened.)

```
var z=0;
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onload=function(){
 console.log(z);
};
x.open('GET','.',true);//asynchronous call
x.send();
setTimeout(function(){
 var i=1e7;
 while(i--);//some time to waste while the asynchronous call finishes.
 var y = new XMLHttpRequest();
 y.open('GET','.',false);//synchronous call
 z=1;
 y.send();
 z=2;
},10);
```

Does anybody know a shorter piece of code that demonstrates this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`y.send()` being "synchronous" will spin the event loop, however it should also [delay events for that DOM window/document](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/content/base/src/nsXMLHttpRequest.cpp#2873) while spinning...

So this seems to be either a bug in the XHR implementation/event dispatcher or a "bug" in the `console` implementation (which is actually *somewhat* async across multiple documents).

Anyway, yet another reason to avoid synchronous XHR: funny reentrancy behaviors. Sounds like you should [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi) if you can reproduce this (I couldn't).

Comment: Strange that you could not reproduce it. I copied the code from above, opened the firebug console in Firefox 24 under the open Stackoverflow page, pasted the code and after pressing run 1 was returned every time.

Comment: Actually I can reproduce it on SO now. I tried on another domain before and using Nightly, which seems to have had different timings or whatever. Still seems to be a bug, though. Or at least "undefined behavior", so my advice to file a bug stands.